# Apache Camel Sticky Http Routing

Tags: java, routes, apache-camel

I want to use apache camel's sticky load balancing to proxy HTTP into Tomcats.

The problem is that sticky load balancer fallbacks to round-robin if it hasn't seen expression value before.

So every request that is proxied goes to another node (as it contains JSESSIONID that load balancer doesn't know). Node answers with a new session, which after I refresh browser won't be taken into account by load balancer cause it doesn't now that ID!

How should I organize Sticky http to http routing with apache camel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build your own load balancer, or extend the existing load balancer, and provide your own logic how to balance.

Just think how you would implement a solution for this use-case without Camel, eg how would the algorithm be. And then implement that algorithm in your custom load balancer.